# Delphi property read/write

Tags: delphi, properties, integer, read-write

is it possible to have different kind of results when declaring property in delphi class?

Example:

`property month: string read monthGet(`**string**`) write monthSet(`**integer**`);`

In the example, I want, with the property month, that when I :
READ, I get a string; SET, I set an integer;

Comment: No. It is not. That's why there are casting properties and functions like `AsString`. If you have more recent version of Delphi, you can define a type like `TMonth` and write helper functions for different sorts of casting. Which version of Delphi do you have ?

Comment: So, How can I do it?

Comment: Just look at the docs http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)

Comment: FWIW, the convention for `property XYZ` is to define the getter as `function GetXYZ: SomeType` and the setter as `procedure SetXYZ(const Value: SomeType)`.

Comment: Delphi/Pascal properties are deeply linked to RTTI so the getter and the setter have to work on the same type. Maybe, and I know at least one, some other lang allow such overloading, but it's mostly because the "property" attribute (for those lang.) is more a syntactic sugar (e.g: using the assign operator instead of calling the setter with parenthesis).

Comment: You could also resort to `Variant` type.

Comment: @FreeConsulting - Then (s)he would have two problems instead of one.

Answer (score 8):

The closest you can get is to use [Operator Overloading](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)) but the Getter/Setter must be the same type. There is no way to change that.

```
program so_26672343;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMonth = record
  private
    FValue: Integer;
    procedure SetValue( const Value: Integer );
  public
    class operator implicit( a: TMonth ): string;
    class operator implicit( a: Integer ): TMonth;
    property Value: Integer read FValue write SetValue;
  end;

  TFoo = class
  private
    FMonth: TMonth;
  public
    property Month: TMonth read FMonth write FMonth;
  end;

  { TMonth }

class operator TMonth.implicit( a: TMonth ): string;
begin
  Result := 'Month ' + IntToStr( a.Value );
end;

class operator TMonth.implicit( a: Integer ): TMonth;
begin
  Result.FValue := a;
end;

procedure TMonth.SetValue( const Value: Integer );
begin
  FValue := Value;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  LFoo: TFoo;
  LMonthInt: Integer;
  LMonthStr: string;
begin
  LFoo := TFoo.Create;
  try
    LMonthInt := 4;
    LFoo.Month := LMonthInt;
    LMonthStr := LFoo.Month;
  finally
    LFoo.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln( E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message );
  end;

end.
```

Comment: I agree that this is a possibility, and I thought of it too, but ISTM a little bit too much, compared to two properties or calling setters and getters directly.

Comment: If you look at the whole concept of an application it is not too much. The domain-types (ValueObjects) are defined only once and were used all over the application. This small sample indeed looks like firing rockets on birds

Comment: If the application has Month as one of the central types, then it makes sense. Otherwise it is a bit too much, IMO. It is an elegant concept to define a type as a record with implicit converters, no doubt.

Comment: I've used this solution for many things, including my own `TDateTimeRec`, `TDateRec`, `TTimeRec`, etc. Also the same for `TVersion` and `TConnectionString`, all records with implicit functions. Such a clever way of casting one value easily into different types :-) Also allowed me to put in some extra functions such as `TDateTimeRec.FriendlyDate: String;` which returns for example `Friday October 31st 2014`

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible. But properties do not have to correspond to internal storage directly, so you can do:

```
private
  FMonth: Integer;
  function GetMonthName: string;
...
  property Month: Integer read FMonth write FMonth;
  property MonthName: string read GetMonthName;
...

procedure TMyClass.GetMonthName: string;
begin
  // code that finds name that corresponds to value of FMonth and returns it in Result.
end;
```

In other words, you'll have to use two properties, one write-only (or normal), one read-only.

Comment: Sorry I have started to write my answer before yours appeared.

Comment: No problem. The solution is pretty obvious, so that two or more came to that conclusion is not unexpected.

Comment: If you allow both writing to the field directly and reading from it you could skip the first property and expose the field instead. I agree that yours is the book solution, but I'm reluctant to define a property for each and every field of my form.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that for a property. A property has a single type.

The obvious way to achieve you goal is to have getter and setter functions that you use directly.

```
function GetMonth: string;
procedure SetMonth(Value: Integer);
```

You might decide to make the type part of the name to reduce confusion in the calling code. Say `GetMonthStr` and `SetMonthOrd`.

You could expose these functions as two separate properties. One read only, the other write only.

Comment: "You could expose these functions as two separate properties" Nice idea ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen Exactly the solution I have proposed. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly do that in Delphi.

---

What you can do is having a "casting property" like:

```
private
  //...
  intMonth: integer
  //...
public
  //...
  property StrMonth: string read GetStrMonth write SetStrMonth;
  property IntMonth: integer read intMonth write intMonth;
  //...
end;

function YourClass.GetStrMonth: string;
begin
  case intMonth of
    1: Result := "January";
    //...
  end;
end;

procedure YourClass.SetStrMonth(Value: string);
begin
  if StrMonth = "January" then
    intMonth := 1;
    //...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You can't use the same name for a field and its property; it won't compile. Capitalizing the property won't save you either as Pascal is case-insensitive. Best practice is to prefix the field with an "F", like Rudy did.